# testcafe issue when returning from a Node ExpressJS redirect

Tags: node.js, reactjs, google-chrome, express, testcafe

I'm currently testing a React front-end application with TestCafe.  Current environment is:

React: 16.3.2
Node: 8.10.0
TestCafe: 0.23.0
MacOS Mojave 10.14.1

We've written about 65 tests which all run great.  We've introduced a Single Sign On component into our application which has posed some automation challenges. Instead of trying to drive TestCafe against our app AND this particular SSO provider, we're using a fake API call instead.

Simplified order of operations for the app during normal usage is:

1. React app starts, detects no SSO credentials
2. Environmental service provides app with a proper SSO URL, react app  redirects user to SSO login page using window.location
3. User logs in and SSO redirects back to our react app with a an additional URL query param & respective value.
4. React app proceeds forward in a 'logged in' state

Pretty basic stuff.

When the React app is being tested, we just provide different URLs which point to a local ExpressJS instance on localhost:3002. When the React app performs a window.location to the fake SSO API (http://localhost:3002/fakeOAuth) the ExpressJS instance simply performs a response.redirect(http://localhost:3000/?sso=fakeCode) and now we are back to our React app with the additional synthetic SSO data.  This scheme works great when not being driven by TestCafe.

When we drive the React app via TestCafe, TestCafe hangs when returning back from the fake SSO call to the React app. After this hang, we have to forcefully kill TestCafe on the command line with a ctrl-c.

Using chrome debug tools and looking at the console output, there is a message:

```
Uncaught TypeError: __get$ is not a function
at hotCreateRequire (bundle.js:73)
at bundle.js:719
at bundle.js:722
```

and a screenshot can be found at the end of this post below.

The Test code:

```
import { Selector } from 'testcafe'
fixture 'Landing Page Body Tests'
.page 'localhost:3000'

test ('Displays correct main welcome title', async t => {
    const landingPage = Selector('.card-title') 
    await t 
        .expect((landingPage).innerText).eql('Welcome, Fakeuser', 'Incorrect Username Found')
})
```

[Screenshot of TestCafe failure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YYrXf.png)

Does anyone have any ideas as to why TestCafe crashes?  I have reworked the test a few times, researched and experimented with using TestCafe's Roles and ClientFunction classes but to no avail.  Any input would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like a bug in TestCafe. The `__get$`function is an internal TestCafe function, and the `__get$ is not a function` error means that TestCafe wasn't able to process your page properly and install its internal functions in the global window object.

I suggest that you create a [new bug report](https://github.com/DevExpress/testcafe/issues/new?template=bug-report.md) in the TestCafe repository, and provide a [HAR report](https://community.box.com/t5/Managing-Content-Troubleshooting/How-to-Generate-a-HAR-File-in-Chrome-IE-Firefox-and-Safari/ta-p/366) and an example that can be used to reproduce the problem.